# How to access integer "iDay2" outside of function "onItemSelected" through the button?

Tags: java, android, function, call

setOnItemSelectedListener.

```
ArrayList<String> ad_days = new ArrayList<String>();
            int ad_endDays = 31;
            for (int i = 1; i <= ad_endDays; i++) {
                ad_days.add(Integer.toString(i));
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> ad_daysAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ad_days);
            spnday2.setAdapter(ad_daysAdapter);
            spnday2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Object objDay2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    CharSequence charDay2= (CharSequence) objDay2;
                    String sDay2= (String) charDay2;
                    int iDay2 = Integer.parseInt(sDay2.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView)
                {
                }
            });
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),iDay2 +" this Day",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Spinner displays day of month in int, but when  I click button I'm not able to access Day from outside of the onItemSelectedListner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring it inside onItemSelected. Make it field variable of your activity.

Eg.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private int iDay2;

    //Your Code
}
```